# Retrieving HTTP parameters in Grails

Tags: grails

the request was sent from an HTML form, the request body contains the form data,how can i retrieve that data in my Grails application.Below is the URL from where i need to retrieve data.I'm a Rookie in Grails so please help me with this.

```
hxxp//localhost:8080/copypolicyNumber/loginaction.jsp?fname=Roger&lname=wallace&city=Des+Moines&pnum=123456&submit=Submit
```

Comment: You asked the same thing here, I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418183/i-wish-to-save-value-entered-by-user-in-textbox-and-send-it-using-http-post-to-s/12429595#12429595

Comment: @TiagoFarias : That Question was closed for some reasons, i need some more help on this as i'm new to Grails.

Comment: Ok. But you need to be more specific with your questions and organize them better, otherwise they will be downvoted or closed again. One thing that you can do right away is to submit your html form to an action instead of a jsp (it should be called a gsp since you're using grails). In the question that was closed I explained a little bit how it works. What do you need now exactly?

Comment: @Lucky you need work better on your questions. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand how this works. So, what did you tried already in your controller? If I understand correctly, you have an old login form and want to redirect this to your grails app?

Comment: @SérgioMichels: Thanks for the advice guys,i'll work on it for sure, and yes you get it right i have an old login form and want to redirect this to my grails app, i have no idea of Grails,just started a few days back, trying to make a form in grails same as my old login page and will try to retrieve those values through controller

Answer (score 3):

As you just started with Grails, I suggest you look at the [screencasts available in the Grails website](http://grails.org/screencasts), and also check the free e-book [Getting Started with Grails](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started) (need registration).

Grails works with the [params](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/params.html) map for both GET and POST requests. Also, it uses an special [url mapping](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#urlmappings) that you need to be aware of.

So, assuming that you have a login controller with the action login and considering that you called the url: `myapp/login/login?fname=Roger&lname=wallace&city=Des+Moines&pnum=123456`

```
class LoginController {

  def login() {
    println params.fname //Roger
    println params.lname //wallace
    println params.city //Des Moines
    println params.pnum //123456
  }  

}
```